# Autofac property Injection in base controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependencies, autofac, code-injection

I have base controlller I try property injection but not work...

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ILoggingService loggingService { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my Autofac config...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// builder.Register(c => new BaseController { loggingService = c.Resolve<ILoggingService>() });
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                   .PropertiesAutowired();

builder.Register(c => new BaseController()).OnActivated(e =>
{
    e.Instance.loggingService = e.Context.Resolve<ILoggingService>();
});
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Aizen.Services"))
                   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use property injection in the first place. Constructor injection is the advised common practice. Autofac will support that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered a concrete type for your `ILoggingService` interface. Without that, Autofac doesn't know what it actually needs to set your property to.

Add something like this (replacing with the real object of course):

```
builder.RegisterType<YourLoggingServiceGoesHere>().As<ILoggingService>();
```

Comment: I have. ı forgat to add it here. thanks answer.. but I have it.

Comment: So the `Aizen.Services` assembly contains the implementation of `ILoggingService`?

Comment: Yes.. ı tried single it -- builder.RegisterType<YourLoggingServiceGoesHere>().As<ILoggingService>();

Comment: I can't see in your code, but have you done something like this `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
builder.Register(c => new BaseController {  loggingService = c.Resolve<ILoggingService>() });
```